# How to complete the "How much money are you planning to spend on your visit to the UK" for a child travelling with both parents?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, applications, children, family

The mother and father are sharing the expenses for the holiday. Family of 4. For example total cost for whole family is 100 pounds. Do I put 25 pounds on each persons application or 100 pounds on the father's application? The website does not accept 0 so should I put 1 pound for the children and mother if the answer is 100 pounds for the father? Or 50 for the mother and 50 for the father as they are sharing the cost?